# why is my kivy app just shut down right after loading?

Tags: android, python-3.x, multithreading, kivy, requirements

I need help to see why my app just shuts down right after the presplanish screen. It is running well on my mac OS X. The app has components from socket, json, and apscheduler.  I did put the apscheduler source folder into the app folder, same level as main.py and as well as adding "apscheduler" into the requirements: line.  this is evident in my spec file, which I will include.  I suspect is maybe it has to do with the socket not connecting to my network?  I can separate that to another screen to make it a manual process.  any help is much appreciated.

main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle, Color
import socket
import json
import threading
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler


class Screen_Manager(ScreenManager):
    screen_1 = ObjectProperty()

class Screen_1(Screen):
    main_display = ObjectProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Screen_1, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.port = 55345

######----2nd thread--------------########
    th = threading.Thread(target=self.server_program)
    th.start()

#####--------start of socket--------------#######
    def server_program(self):
    # get the hostname
        self.host = socket.gethostname()
        self.ip_address = socket.gethostbyname(self.host)
        server_socket = socket.socket()  # get instance
        server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEPORT, 1)
        server_socket.bind((self.ip_address, self.port))

        server_socket.listen(2)
        conn, address = server_socket.accept()  # accept new connection

        b = b''
        while True:
            data = conn.recv(1024)
            if data:
                b += data
                self.utf_data = json.loads(data.decode('utf-8'))
                self.main_display.text = self.utf_data
            if not data:
                conn, address = server_socket.accept()  # accept new connection
        server_socket.close()

class MainApp(App):

    def build(self):
        self.title = "Number Display App"
        self.sm = Screen_Manager()
        return self.sm

if __name__=="__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

main.kv

```
<Screen_Manager>:
    Screen_1:

<Screen_1>:
    id: screen_1
    name: "first"

    main_display: display_1


    Label:
        id: display_1
        text: ""
        font_size: "450sp"
        color: 1,0,1,1
        background_color: 0.1, 0.5, 0.6,
```

here is my .spec file (at least the lines for requirement:

```
# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3,ivy,apscheduler
```

internet permission is turn on as well.

```
# (list) Permissions
android.permissions = INTERNET
```

here is the photo that shows I have included the file folder for apscheduler.

[image]

thanks again.

Comment: Try running `buildozer -v android debug deploy run logcat` to see what is happening. If your android version is 21 or greater, you will need to request the internet permission in your code. See [the documentation](https://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/apis/#runtime-permissions).

Comment: hi @JohnAnderson thanks for always give me feedback when I post of Kivy.  I tried your commend.  it debug fine and still shuts down.  I then tried it without the "apscheduler" but code it only with threading.  Now the app does not shut down, however I found another problem where my app is refusing socket connection.  I will have to fingutre out what's happening and see.  I will post another one after I am stumble again.  the code is updated now.